# Minimum impact proguard configuration on Android

Tags: android-proguard

I have a simple problem: A third party dependency jar (BouncyCastle) that I want to shrink to avoid the 65k method dex limit.
But using ProGuard creates thousands (literally!) of new problems (in addition to the warnings it generates): Explicit coupling between my third party libraries and proguard config files which to me seems ridiculous. But enough bashing of ProGuard...

**Is there a way to tell ProGuard to exclude most of the code and only optimize/shrink/etc the one library that I have a problem with?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31508908/1643723

Comment: Thanks but this does not look like minimum impact. I don't want to sanitize a jar file and then check it in as I want it to be hassle-free to update my dependencies. So an automated way.

Comment: Have you read the entire answer? At the end it provides Proguard configuration, that allows you to do exactly that: list Proguard-compatible packages once and update the list only when you need to achieve better shrinking. If you use that configuration, you won't have to update it each time a new library is added to the project (because it excludes all not-listed packages by default). Sorry, there is no magical way to automate any more than that.